# Authenticated spider pagination. 302 redirect. reqvalidation.asps - page not found

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, scrapy, session-cookies

I have a scrapy sider that can log into ancestry.com successfully. I then use that authenticated session to return a new link and can scrape the first page of the new link successfully. The issue happens when I try to go to the second page. I get a 302 redirect debug message, and this url:  https://secure.ancestry.com/error/reqvalidation.aspx?aspxerrorpath=http%3a%2f%2fsearch.ancestry.com%2ferror%2fPageNotFound&msg=&ti=0>.

I followed the documentation and have follow some recommendations here to get me this far. Do I need a session token for each page? if so how do I got about doing that?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from ..items import AncItem

class AncestrySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ancestry'

    def start_requests(self):
        return[
            FormRequest(
               'https://www.ancestry.com/account/signin?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ancestry.com',
                formdata={"username": "foo", "password": "bar"},
                callback=self.after_login
            )
        ]

    def after_login(self, response):
        if "authentication failed".encode() in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return
        else:
            return Request(url='https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/nypl/?name=_Wang&count=50&name_x=_1',
                           callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        all_products = response.xpath("//tr[@class='tblrow record']")
        for product in all_products:
            loader = ItemLoader(item=AncItem(), selector=product, response=response)
            loader.add_css('Name', '.srchHit')
            loader.add_css('Arrival_Date', 'td:nth-child(3)')
            loader.add_css('Birth_Year', 'td:nth-child(4)')
            loader.add_css('Port_of_Departure', 'td:nth-child(5)')
            loader.add_css('Ethnicity_Nationality', 'td:nth-child(6)')
            loader.add_css('Ship_Name', 'td:nth-child(7)')
            yield loader.load_item()

            next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="ancBtn sml green icon iconArrowRight"]').extract_first()
            if next_page is not None:
                next_page_link = response.urljoin(next_page)
                yield scrapy.Request( url=next_page_link, callback=self.parse)
```

I tired adding some request header information. I tried adding the cookie information to the request header, but that did not work. I've tried using only the USER agents that are listed in the POST packages.

Right now I only get 50 results. I should be getting hundreds after crawling all the pages.

Comment: Scrapy results:

Comment: DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://search.ancestry.com/search/collections/nypl/%3Ca%20class=%22ancBtn%20sml%20green%20icon%20iconArrowRight%22%20href=%22?name=_Wang&amp;name_x=_1&amp;count=50&amp;fh=
50&amp;fsk=MDs0OTs1MA-61--61-%22%3E%3C/a%3E> from <GET https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/nypl/%3Ca%20class=%22ancBtn%20sml%20green%20icon%20iconArrowRight%22%20href=%22?name=_Wang&amp;name_x=_1&amp;count=50&amp;fh=50&amp;fsk=MDs0OTs1MA-61--61-%22%3E%3C/a%
3E>

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. It had nothing to do with the authentication to the website. I needed to find a different way to approach pagination. I resorted to using the page url for pagination instead of following the "next page" button link.